# Sourcing a shell script from JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

Imagine we have a `env.sh` with following content.

```
export SOME_VAL="abcd"
```

We want to source this shell script from a JS (node.js) script `bootstrap.js`.

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const cmd = '. ' + pathToEnvScript;
childProcess.exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log(stdout);
})
```

Here is how we call the `bootstrap.js`.

```
echo $SOME_VAL # empty
node bootstrap.js
echo $SOME_VAL # empty
```

Why the sourcing doesn't take any effect? The sourcing works if we call `source env.sh` from terminal, but doesn't work for `node bootstrap.js`.

Comment: Why would you even want to use nodejs to source a shell script?? I guess you need to `export` your variables out of child scope.

Comment: Limited by some project requirement. I'm curious about how.

Comment: Gave you an option, hope it helps. I would need more details about your requirement to workaround the obvious non feasibility of it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that

> a child process cannot modify its parent env (unless you hack your shell)

the best you can do is

> **make nodejs tell your shell what to do to update its environment** as it would have if it had sourced the script itself.

I assume you are only interested in variables and not functions.

Here is your solution.

**bootstrap.js**:

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const script = process.argv[2];
childProcess.exec("env > ./1.txt; . ./"+script+" >/dev/null 2>&1; env > ./2.txt; diff 1.txt 2.txt | grep '^>'", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    stdout.split('\n').forEach((line) => console.log(line.substr(2)));
})
```

and how you should call it:

```
echo $SOME_VAL # empty
eval `node bootstrap.js ./file.sh`
echo $SOME_VAL # abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

`childProcess.exec(command)` [spawns a shell then executes the `command` within that shell.](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) Using `export` makes variables available to child processes of the shell, but not to its parent. Node and the shell from which you invoke Node never see the variable.

Answer (score 0):

this is not working for at least two reasons.  `source` is a [Bash internal command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-source), and node spawns `/bin/sh` by default.  And even if you told `child_process.exec` to spawn a Bash shell:

> `child_process.exec("ls", { shell: "/bin/bash" }, (err, stdout) => ())`

then the `source`'d variables would be added to the environment of the shell process, not the environment of node.js .

I don't know what the exact specific requirements are for your project but your best bet might be to open the file in node and parse its contents to find key/value pairs and set node's environment that way.

Comment: That was my first thought too. However the sourced script may compute variables. So a basic parsing of `my_var="abc"` may not work great.